# Cordova css background-image missing with Polymer on ios/safari

Tags: cordova, polymer

I use CSS to set a background image for a Polymer element. This works on the web, but not inside a Cordova web app. I want to fix this.

I can hack Polymer, but I am a Cordova newbie, and need help tracing url munging code inside Cordova.

Polymer parses css internally, and munges the css urls. On ios, following statements:

`background-image: url('../img/health_background.png'); } 
    <img src="../img/health_background.png">`

will be replaced with:

`background-image: url(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FE5C8C06-E9B3-4F75-B9E7-40D6FD54FC0B/SyntraJS.app/www/img/health_background.png)
<img src="file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FE5C8C06-E9B3-4F75-B9E7-40D6FD54FC0B/SyntraJS.app/www/img/health_background.png">`

by Polymer's HTMLImports polyfill.

Looking at these elements inside Safari's debugger, the `<img>` tag looks fine, but the `background-image:` css is not there. I assume Safari did not like its syntax, and threw it out.

If I add the same `background-image` property in Safari's debugger, it works.

Any suggestions about:
- why did Safari ignore original `background-image`?
- Are all urls in Cordova apps absolute file urls?

Comment: Tracing this through, it is Polymer's shim fault!

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: No, got tired of tracing it through, it's a hairy path munging code. I implemented some kind of workaround, but forgot what it was.